# psycopg2.OperationalError after 20/30 minutes

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, flask, psycopg2

## Explaination

Hello, I'm currently doing a web app with **Python/Flask**. This application will do some tests on Router/Switches and store results in a **postgreSQL** database. I'm showing this results in a table using **psycopg2** to connect to the database and extract these data.

This app is designed to run 24 hours a day. But the problem is, after 20/30 minutes I have a 500 Internal Server Error while I'm loading a webpage of the app. When I'm looking the logs here is the error :
`psycopg2.OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request.`

If I refresh a second times, I have another error message :
`psycopg2.InterfaceError: connection already closed`

And if I refresh a third time, it's working again but it's not possible to run this app in production if it crashes every 20/30 minutes.

I don't understand why I have this error and how I could resolve it. Here is some code :

## Some code

**main.py**

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "mysecretkey"
app.config['PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME'] = timedelta(minutes=30)
app.config['postgreSQL_pool'] = psycopg2.pool.SimpleConnectionPool(1, 20,
    user = "username",
    password = "password",
    host = "myserver",
    port = "5432",
    database = "stackoverflow")

def get_db():
    if 'db' not in g:
        g.db = app.config['postgreSQL_pool'].getconn()
    return g.db

@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_conn(e):
    db = g.pop('db', None)
    if db is not None:
        app.config['postgreSQL_pool'].putconn(db)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def home():
    """
    Retourne la page principale avec la liste des équipements + export CSV possible
    """
    db = get_db()
    cursor = db.cursor()

    mois_lot = "Juin"
    cursor.execute("""SELECT *
                  FROM stackoverflow WHERE lot='%s'""" % (mois_lot))
    liste_lot = cursor.fetchall()


    count = Check.count(mois_lot, cursor)
    count_ok = Check.count_ok(mois_lot, cursor)
    count_ko = Check.count_ko(mois_lot, cursor)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        liste_lot.insert(0, ('IP Admin',
                             'Resultat',
                             'Equipement',
                             'Date derniere verification'))
        cursor.close()
        return excel.make_response_from_array(liste_lot, "csv", file_name="export_lot")
    else:
        cursor.close()
        return render_template('index.html',
                               value=liste_lot,
                               value2=count,
                               value3=count_ok,
                               value4=count_ko)
```

**check.py**

```
class Check():
    """
    Classe check des équipements
    """

    @staticmethod
    def count(lot, cursor):
        """
        Compte le nombre d'équipements
        """
        cursor.execute("""SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stackoverflow WHERE lot='%s'""" % (lot))
        nb_equipement = cursor.fetchall()
        nb_equipement = nb_equipement[0][0]
        return nb_equipement

    @staticmethod
    def count_ok(lot, cursor):
        """
        Compte le nombre d'équipement OK
        """
        cursor.execute("""SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stackoverflow WHERE resultat='OK' and lot='%s'""" % (lot))
        nb_ok = cursor.fetchall()
        nb_ok = nb_ok[0][0]
        return nb_ok

    @staticmethod
    def count_ko(lot, cursor):
        """
        Compte le nombre d'équipement KO
        """
        cursor.execute("""SELECT COUNT(*)
                            FROM stackoverflow WHERE lot='%s' and (resultat='KO' OR resultat IS NULL)""" % (lot))
        nb_ko = cursor.fetchall()
        nb_ko = nb_ko[0][0]
        return nb_ko
```

## Expected

I would like the app to not crash every 20/30 minutes. I think, I open and close the database connection correctly but maybe I'm wrong.

Thanks in advance for any help.